# Adding a Second window in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, xaml

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="POGPOS.Views.MainWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:POGPOS.Views" 
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Loaded="StartApi"
  Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Grid>
     <Button Content="Open Window" Click="ButtonClicked" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
     Margin="379,264,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" />
 </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
     public MainWindow()
     {
      InitializeComponent();
     }

   private void ButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    SubWindow subWindow = new SubWindow();
    subWindow.Show();
     }
 }
```

SubWindow.xaml:

```
     <Window x:Class="POGPOS.Views.Subwindow"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:POGPOS.Views"
      mc:Ignorable="d"
      Name="Detail"  Height="2400" Width="1765" AllowsTransparency ="True">
     <Grid>
       <Button Content="Open Window" Click="ButtonClicked" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
       Margin="379,264,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" />
    </Grid>
   </Window>
```

SubWindow.xaml.cs

```
         public partial class DetailView : Window
          {
           public DetailView() : base()
              {
                 --------------------------------
               }
         }
```

But the error here is : InvalidOperationException: Window must be the root of the tree. Cannot add Window as a child of Visual.

Comment: The class name you have in SubWindow.xaml (`POGPOS.Views.Subwindow`), doesn't match the one you have in SubWindow.xaml.cs (`DetailView`, which is assumedly `POGPOS.Views.DetailView`). That's the first problem I see.

Comment: Oh  yeah I have the same name in my program it's just here that I changed it for the sake of clarity.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Can you change the code in your question to match the code in your project, please.